# Changing the word "password" at login

Tags: login, password, prompt

Wanted to know if there was a way to change the word password here to say passcode? We use a custom application that authenticates users through passcodes and to not confuse users, I wanted to change the text.

user@192.168.0.5's password:

I found some articles on the sshd_config and PM files but I cannot figure it out. Any help would be great.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to change that without going in the source code.

Comment: @JuliePelletier a language translation file maybe?

Comment: @roaima For OpenSSH, the password prompt is hardcoded. (`snprintf(prompt, sizeof(prompt), "%.30s@%.128s's password: ", authctxt->server_user, host);`). I would personally not type a password at a prompt I didn't recognise.

Comment: Since password and passcode have exactly the same number of letters you could probably just edit the binary, e.g. with Perl. The downside is that any package manager will say that the program has been tampered with.

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks; that's interesting to see. I'd assumed just about everything was written with translation in mind.

Comment: @roaima You're thinking of GNU software, I believe  ;-)

Comment: Are you sure that this phrase is in the server, instead of the client?

Comment: Are users always logging in using SSH?

Comment: @Gilles yes, all users using this platform will be forced to use SSH. No other protocol is open.

Comment: @everyone, thank you for all your responses. I might have to just stick with the Banner to inform users to auth with a passcode.